# An example where start and stop GPS is implemented

Tags: android

I am working on an app that involves starting and stopping the GPS in code. I have not tried this before. Completely clueless. Would anyone be willing to provide a page with some implementation of these principles? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is many explanations/examples in the Android Dev Guide : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html

Comment: Thanks Lyrkan. However, I am looking for something with alittle more detailed explanation. Any ideas?